# Magento2: How to create custom model collection?

Tags: magento2, frontend, cart-items

I want to create a custom cart item collection model.

I want to get already added cart items collection from the database.

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 files:

- Model
- Resource Model
- Resource Model Collection

Assuming your module name is: `Amir/Prince` => `app/code/Amir/Prince`

So :

1. **Model :**  `app/code/Amir/Prince/Model/Mymodel.php`

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Amir\Prince\Model;

   class Mymodel extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
   {
       const CACHE_TAG = 'amir_prince_mymodel';
       protected $_cacheTag = 'amir_prince_mymodel';
       protected $_eventPrefix = 'amir_prince_mymodel';

       protected function _construct()
       {
           $this->_init('Amir\Prince\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
       }

       public function getIdentities()
       {
           return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
       }

       public function getDefaultValues()
       {
           $values = [];
           return $values;
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Resource Model :** `app/code/Amir/Prince/Model/ResourceModel/Post.php`

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Amir\Prince\Model\ResourceModel;


   class Post extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
   {

       public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
       )
       {
           parent::__construct($context);
       }

       protected function _construct()
       {
           $this->_init('amir_prince_post', 'post_id'); //post_id : Primary key of your database table
       }

   }
   ```
3. **Resource Model Collection :** `app/code/Amir/Prince/Model/ResourceModel/Post/Collection.php`

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Amir\Prince\Model\ResourceModel\Post;


   class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
   {

       protected $_idFieldName = 'post_id';
       protected $_eventPrefix = 'amir_prince_post_collection';
       protected $_eventObject = 'post_collection';

       /**
       * Define resource model
       *
       * @return void
       */
       protected function _construct()
       {
            $this->_init('Amir\Prince\Model\Mymodel', 'Amir\Prince\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
       }

       }
   ```

Now to **call your collection**, you need to call this class `Amir\Prince\Model\GoFactory` where you want to use it, `MymodelFactory` => model class name + `Factory` word.

Exemple in your controller :

```
app/code/Amir/Prince/Controller/Index/Index.php
```

```
<?php
namespace Amir\Prince\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_mymodelFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Amir\Prince\Model\MymodelFactory $mymodelFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_mymodelFactory = $mymodelFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->_mymodelFactory->create();
        $collection = $post->getCollection();
        foreach($collection as $col){
            var_dump($col->getData());
        }
        exit();
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

For more [informations](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html).

Comment: I will check and update you soon.