# Getting a table first row from repository

Tags: magento2, module, repositories

I'm building my first Magento 2 module, and I'm a bit stuck.

First of all, this is what I have so far (I'm still fixing the coding standards on all the pages). https://github.com/moloni/magento2

I have a doubt about something a bit simple... How do I get the first row of the table I created?

I made a repository, created all the files for the Tokens model, and I can access the first row using the following:

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $this->tokensRow = $collection->getFirstItem();
}
```

But, since the method `getCollection` says it will be deprecated, what can I use to the get the first row of a table?

Every method I saw was using the getCollection mehtod, and that's why my doubt.

Also, if I want to read the first row and update the row if it exists, or create a new one if it does not, how can I do so without the `getCollection`?

Still learning how to properly code for Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Model :**

You can use `load()` if you know your first item id.

```
public function getFirstItem() {
    $id = "1";
    return $this->_yourmodel->load($id);
}
```

**Collection :**

In collection, you can also use `limit()`

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1); //It's better on performance than getFirstItem()
```

**Update:**

Here is how to get a collection :

You need these files:

`1. Model`

`2. Resource Model`

`3. Resource Model Collection`

Then you call your modelFactory to get collection

```
$col = $this->_modelFactory->create();
$collection = $col->getCollection();
```

Look the full exemple [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/250307/48355)

Comment: Well, I can't guarantee that the id is 1 (I can make it be, but I didn't want to guarantee). The problem with collections, is the deprecated notice with getCollection, I got it working with getCollection, but I can't see how to solve this without the getCollection...

Comment: Also checked out the load, and shows as deprecated

Comment: Why deprecated ? please look my update